# Dinosaur bones found

Tags: dinosaurs

I found a bone in 120 metres under the ground which has nuclear radiation. Can you help me to recognize this bone?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]

It was found in a clay quarry near Odessa Ukraine.

Comment: Not with just that image. You want pictures with something for scale from all sides including the broken section. We need to get a good idea of the shape and size. The formation it is found in would also be helpful but not absolutely necessary. The radioactivity is irrelevant.